# storing char in an array of integers

Tags: c, arrays

I have some doubt regarding this program,Here we are creating integer to array and storing char inside that

> THINK IN CASE WHEN WE WRITE THE INFIX TO POSTFIX PROGRAM, SAME STACK OPERATION FUNCTION WILL BE USED THERE

And we will store parenthesis and operand in the stack, i want to ask whether the ASCII value stored in the `stack->array` 
And why is there no need of typecasting
And since integer require 4 bytes of memory then how 1 byte char are stored in that array not only storing but how we can access   all char variables using that integer array because according to pointer arithmatic `*(array+i)`will be 4 byte ahead if array is pointer to integer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

// Stack type
struct Stack
{
    int top;
    unsigned capacity;
    int* array;
};

// Stack Operations
struct Stack* createStack( unsigned capacity )
{
    struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*) malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));

    if (!stack) return NULL;

    stack->top = -1;
    stack->capacity = capacity;
    stack->array = (int*) malloc(stack->capacity * sizeof(int));

    if (!stack->array) return NULL;

    return stack;
}

int isEmpty(struct Stack* stack)
{
     return stack->top == -1 ;
}

char peek(struct Stack* stack)
{
    return stack->array[stack->top];
}

char pop(struct Stack* stack)
{
    if (!isEmpty(stack))
        return stack->array[stack->top--] ;
    return '$';
}

void push(struct Stack* stack, char op)
{
    stack->array[++stack->top] = op;
}


// The main function that returns value of a given postfix expression
int evaluatePostfix(char* exp)
{
    // Create a stack of capacity equal to expression size
    struct Stack* stack = createStack(strlen(exp));
    int i;

    // See if stack was created successfully
    if (!stack) return -1;

    // Scan all characters one by one
    for (i = 0; exp[i]; ++i)
    {
        // If the scanned character is an operand (number here),
        // push it to the stack.
        if (isdigit(exp[i]))
            push(stack, exp[i] - '0');

        // If the scanned character is an operator, pop two
        // elements from stack apply the operator
        else
        {
            int val1 = pop(stack);
            int val2 = pop(stack);
            switch (exp[i])
            {
                case '+': push(stack, val2 + val1); break;
                case '-': push(stack, val2 - val1); break;
                case '*': push(stack, val2 * val1); break;
                case '/': push(stack, val2/val1); break;
            }
        }
    }
    return pop(stack);
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    char exp[] = "231*+9-";
    printf ("Value of %s is %d", exp, evaluatePostfix(exp));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please write `struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*) malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));` as `struct Stack *stack = malloc(sizeof *stack);`, it's shorter and more DRY. As to your question, characters in C are small integers, which is why there's no problem in storing `char` values in `int` variables, they're both integers and you can be sure any `char` fits in an `int` (there's some complexity regarding signedness, but let's ignore that).

Comment: a `char` is just a number, the only special thing about it is that often it is interpreted as a character. `sizeof(int) > sizeof(char)`, so there there is no problem with assigning a `char` to an `int`

Comment: There is no need to cast a void* to any other poitner while assigning. Only in C++ you need to do that (but there you don't use malloc ofc ;) )

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` is the smallest addressable unit of the machine that can contain basic character set. **It is an integer type**. Actual type can be either signed or unsigned. It contains CHAR_BIT bits.

It size is almost always less than the size of an int. So a `char` can be easily stored in an `int`.

> how we can access all char variables using that integer array because according to pointer arithmatic *(array+i)will be 4 byte ahead if array is pointer to integer

This is possible because when you are storing a `char` into an `int`, you are storing them at intervals the size of int. Since `top` is an `int`, the pointer arithmetic on it (++) will increase its address value by the size of an `int`.

```
stack->array[++stack->top] = op;
```

And that's what happens when you are retrieving the `char` also.  The pointer arithmetic on `top`(--) will decrease its address value by the size of an `int`.

```
return stack->array[stack->top--] ;
```

So it works without any problem.

Comment: When I am printing `sizeof('b')` it is printing 4 which is the size of int
but it should print 1 because i am writing b in quotes 'b' and i am assuming that is a char

Comment: In C, the type of a character constant like 'a' is actually an `int`, with size of 4 (or some other implementation-dependent value). If you print `sizeof(char)`, you will get `1`.

Comment: Does this answer your question?